# aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Can't parse reply keyboard markup json object

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Честно говоря, даже не знаю как задать данный вопрос так, чтобы меня не закидали здесь помидорами. Тут были уже аналогичные вопросы, но они не были подробны и соответственно ответа я никакого не нашёл для себя.
Я учусь писать телеграмм бота на Python с помощью фреймворка aiogram. Всё шло вроде нормально, но потом я столкнулся с проблемой, когда хотел создать кнопки в боте. Кода многовато для поста, поэтому покажу пока только его часть. Если кому-то понадобится больше подробностей в случае если что-то будет неясно - залью остальную часть и скину ссылку. Скрипт в функциях клиентской части я пока убрал, кроме первой функции, поскольку там много кода для этого сообщения, и это к делу не относится. Бот разрабатывается в виртуальной среде venv.

Код 1 (создание кнопок)

```
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardRemove

button_one = KeyboardButton('/start')
button_two = KeyboardButton('/help')
button_three = KeyboardButton('/weather')
button_four = KeyboardButton('/opening_hours')

keyboard_client = ReplyKeyboardMarkup()

keyboard_client.add(button_one).add(button_two).add(button_three).add(button_four)
```

Код 2 (клиентская часть, выводит сообщения для пользователя при введении определённых команд):

```
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from create_bot import disp, svbot
# create_bot - файл со скриптом создания бота (svbot = Bot(token=os.getenv('TOKEN')) disp = Dispatcher(svbot)
from keyboard import client_keyboard
# keyboard - папка со скриптами кнопок

import datetime
import requests
import time

async def start (m: types.Message):
    await m.answer(type(client_keyboard.keyboard_client))
    await m.answer(client_keyboard.keyboard_client)
    await svbot.send_message(m.from_user.id, 'Ну чё, поехали?', reply_markup=client_keyboard)



async def dnipro_weather(dw: types.Message):
    # выводит сообщение о сегодняшней погоде


async def help(messaga: types.Message):
    # помощь


async def open_close(m: types.Message):
    # показывает сообщение о часах работы магазина/заведения


def reg_handlers_client(disp: Dispatcher):
    disp.register_message_handler(start, commands=['start'])
    disp.register_message_handler(help, commands=['help'])
    disp.register_message_handler(dnipro_weather, commands=['weather'])
    disp.register_message_handler(open_close, commands=['opening_hours'])
```

Проблема состоит в атрибуте reply_markup=client_keyboard в первой функции. По идее с помощью этого атрибута должны были создаться кнопки в боте. Но вместо этого я получаю ошибку:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-9' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\OpenServer\domains\bots.ant\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=BadRequest("Can't parse reply keyboard markup json object")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OpenServer\domains\bots.ant\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\OpenServer\domains\bots.ant\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\OpenServer\domains\bots.ant\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\OpenServer\domains\bots.ant\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\OpenServer\domains\bots.ant\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\OpenServer\domains\bots.ant\handlers\client.py", line 14, in start
await svbot.send_message(m.from_user.id, 'Ну чё, поехали?', reply_markup=client_keyboard)
  File "C:\OpenServer\domains\bots.ant\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 334, in send_message
result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_MESSAGE, payload)
  File "C:\OpenServer\domains\bots.ant\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 231, in request
return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\OpenServer\domains\bots.ant\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "C:\OpenServer\domains\bots.ant\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "C:\OpenServer\domains\bots.ant\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 141, in detect
raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Can't parse reply keyboard markup json object
```

Прочитав это, и полистав интернет, я понял, что должен был распарситься JSON объект, присвоенный переменной keyboard_client, который является основой для создания тех самых кнопок. Вот эта ошибка "Can't parse reply keyboard markup json object" - ума не приложу, почему она выскакивает. JSON объект, который должен парситься, выглядит так:

```
{"keyboard": [[{"text": "/start"}], [{"text": "/help"}], [{"text": "/weather"}], [{"text": "/opening_hours"}]]}
```

Вопрос: почему этот объект не парсится? В чём может быть проблема? Подскажите пожалуйста, потому что я даже не знаю, что тут можно попробовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сократить код

```
button_one = KeyboardButton('/start')
button_two = KeyboardButton('/help')
button_three = KeyboardButton('/weather')
button_four = KeyboardButton('/opening_hours')

keyboard_client = ReplyKeyboardMarkup()

keyboard_client.add(button_one).add(button_two).add(button_three).add(button_four)


@dp.message_handler(Command('start'))
async def start (m: types.Message):
    await m.answer('Ну чё, поехали?', reply_markup=keyboard_client)


@dp.message_handler(Command('weather'))
async def dnipro_weather(m: types.Message):
    await m.answer('Ты в попал в хендлер dnipro_weather')

@dp.message_handler(Command('help'))
async def help(m: types.Message):
    await m.answer('Ты в попал в хендлер help')


@dp.message_handler(Command('opening_hours'))
async def open_close(m: types.Message):
    # показывает сообщение о часах работы магазина/заведения
    await m.answer('Ты в попал в хендлер open_close')
```

Comment: Спасибо, но там было дело не в сокращении кода, а то что я вместо JSON-объекта с кнопками пытался парсить целый модуль, т. е. вместо reply_markup=keyboard_klient написал reply_markup=client_keyboard. По сути ответ был у меня под носом, прямо в моём вопросе, моя ошибка из-за невнимательности. 
Но всё равно с меня плюс за помощь. :)

Answer (score 0):

иногда может быть такое, когда забыли поставить `()`

Вместо `("Hello World",reply_markup=config.get_rate)`

Надо `("Hello World",reply_markup=config.get_rate())`